# Access variable inside javascript function (generator)

Tags: javascript, generator

In Javascript suppose I have a generator which i cannot modify the source code of. I iterate through a couple of times and now want to look inside at the variables of the generator. How can I do this without changing the code of the generator itself? More concretely -

```
async function* myGen(){
    while (true){
        let a = something
        yield something_else
    } 
}

let gen = myGen()

for await (const data of gen){
    if(data === special_value){
        let my_a = get_value_of_a(gen) // this is the function i want
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. A generator is still a function, and you cannot just get a value of a variable that's out of scope (in scope of a function). This seems a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Typically, if you have a function (generator or otherwise) you should never rely on internal state of it.

Comment: Since you cannot modify the code of the generator function I assume it belongs to a different package that you use in your project. The internals of the generator function can change on the next version of the package without changing its external behaviour. Assuming you can do what you want, such a change will break your code (to not mention that your code is already broken in the instant you implement `get_value_of_a()`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the generator doesn't yield the value of `a` (or something that gives you access to the value of `a`), you cannot access it. `a` is a local variable within the generator function. It's not accessible from outside that function (unless you do something to make it accessible, but you said you can't modify the generator function).

Putting it another way: The value of `a` is private information held inside the generator object the function returns. You can't access that private information if the generator object doesn't provide a means of doing so, which the ones created by generator functions don't by default.

Comment: Thanks! It seems a bit unfortunate that this is the case. I believe in python its possible to do this.

Comment: @AdamS. - I don't do Python but that would be *very* surprising, exposing the local variables of a function like that. I don't see anything [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html) suggesting you can do that. It doesn't make sense to expose internals to callers. If the generator wanted to expose that, it could easily do `yield { a, something_else }` so the consumer of the generator could use either of those values.

Comment: @AdamS. - Note that if you're trying to *change* `a`, insert a value into the generator, that's possible (provided the generator supports it), by passing a value to the generator's `next` method. But only if the generator uses the result of the `yield` expression. (FWIW, I go into the details of that in Chapters 6 and 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Answer (score 0):

Global variables can be accessed from anywhere in a class or namespace. ... If a variable is defined in any of these scopes, it will be visible to the current scope and the ones that are nested within it. In simple terms: A variable declared within a loop will not be visible outside the loop.

```
    var global = "Global Variable"; //Define global variable outside of function.
​    function setGlobal(){
    global = "Hello World!";
    };
    setGlobal();
    console. log(global); //This will print out "Hello World"
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I gave him possible variant of accessing variable inside javascript function

Comment: OP asks how to do this *without* changing the generator function. Declaring a global variable would require a change to the function.